# SystemVerilog vs VHDL - Is there a way in SV to do late definitions of array sizes?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

In VHDL I can make my modules arbitrary.  Bus sizes flow from higher levels. That way I don't need to edit all my code every time I reuse a module.

Consider the following (incomplete) examples (This is a toy example to try to illustrate a point.)

In both examples:
The size of bus is implicit and late defined
The structure of displaystruct is made elsewhere.
The definition of decoder function is made elsewhere.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.displaylib.all;

-- In writing like this I can instance 'm' on any size bus without changing it.

entity m is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        bus : in std_logic_vector;
        display : out displaystruct
    );
end entity;

architecture example of m is
begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then
        display <= decoder(bus);
    end if;

end architure;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.displaylib.all;

entity top is
end entity;

architecture example of top is

signal clk     : std_logic;
signal bus     : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  --Late definition of bus
signal display : displaystruct;
begin

    controller : m port map (
        clk => clk,
        bus => bus,
        display => display);

end architecture;
```

I would like to do the same in SystemVerilog but I don't see how.  You can't have arrays of undefined size  (e.g. [])

```
`include "displaylib"

// Non working example as the array size of bus needs to be known

module m (
    input logic clk,
    input logic [] bus,
    output displaystruct display
)


    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        display = decoder(bus);
    end
    
endmodule;


module top;

    logic clk;
    logic [15:0] bus;  //Late definition of bus
    displaystruct display;
    
    controller m (
        .clk(clk),
        .bus(bus),
        .display(display)
    );

endmodule;
```

Comment: Interesting and I also don't know if it is possible, but: defining a parameter with the bus size at *top* module and passing it to the *m* module at the instantiation would not solve this cleanly?

Comment: By using a parameter you have a global, in any language that is not nice.  I know I could use a typedef or use a module parameter (as I could a generic in VHDL) but that is not the question.  This question is about late definition.  A parameter would need the value either passed or updated in every instance.  That creates a lot of work and error in a large design.  Is there a more elegant synthesisable solution?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Out of context of HDLs, I agree that *global variables* are a bad thing but *top level definitions*, which are used by other dependent definitions (so the same thing is not defined more than once), are not the same thing (and solve the problem of editing the modules upon reuse). The question is indeed quite broad and maybe even removing *"of array sizes"* from the end of the title would allow this understanding. I'm looking forward for the suggestions here.

Comment: Not sure why you think parameters in HDL are 'global' and 'not nice'. That's debatable in software languages, but it has nothing special to do with HDLs because parameters are something simply elaborated by Synthesiser to numerics ahead of synthesis. Parameters are how ASIC/FPGA engineers build configurable designs, as in your requirements

Comment: @Mitu: I am asking how to write SystemVerilog that does not require configuration, like I can in VHDL.

Comment: Devnull's first comment is the solution to your question and standard design practice for synthesisability. If that's not what you want, I guess you have an XY problem here.

Comment: @JasonM In both VHDL and Verilog, your `displaystruct` is never defined. It has to be defined _somewhere_.

Comment: @dave_59  In VHDL, we know that displaystruct is just a simple constained type (and not a record with unconstrained elements - although VHDL allows this now) because it was not sized in the signal declaration.   It would be interesting to know if SV supports structures with unconstrained objects - and no constraints on the interface - I do this all the time in OSVVM VHDL verification components - handy feature.

Comment: @dave_59  I already state that this is an incomplete toy example and that displaystruct etc are defined elsewhere.  That is removed as it adds nothing to the question.  If you notice I do include a library in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in verilog by defining parameters in the module. You can override these parameters when you instantiate module inside top.
Here is the example using your code:

```
module controller #(parameter BUS_WIDTH=16)  //Here 16 is default value.
     ( input logic clk,
       input logic[BUS_WIDTH-1:0] bus,
       output displaystruct display
     )

        always @(posedge clk)
        begin
            display = decoder(bus);
        end

endmodule

module top;
        parameter FINAL_BUS_WIDTH = 32;
            
        logic clk;
        logic [BUS_WIDTH-1:0] bus;  //Late definition of bus
        displaystruct display;
        
        controller m #(BUS_WIDTH = FINAL_BUS_WIDTH) // THis will create module with bus width 32
            .clk(clk),
            .bus(bus),
            .display(display)
        );

        controller m2 // THis will create module with bus width 16
                .clk(clk),
                .bus(bus),
                .display(display)
            );

        controller m3 #(BUS_WIDTH = 4) // THis will create module with bus width 4
                .clk(clk),
                .bus(bus),
                .display(display)
            );
        
    endmodule
```

In this example, I created BUS_WIDTH parameter in the module m whose default value is 16.
This parameter can be overridden whenever you are instantiating the module m.